# Pyspark: non-matching values in date time column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The format of most of my (string) dates in my pyspark column looks like this:
Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0000 2021

I want to convert it into a date format like this: 01-07-2021
And I have found a way that works, unfortunately only when the column is clean aka when the string has the follwing format:'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'

This is the code I used:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, to_date, to_utc_timestamp

# Converting date string format
def getDate(x):
    if x is not None:
        return str(datetime.strptime(x,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    else:
        return None

# UDF declaration
date_fn = udf(getDate, StringType())

# Converting datatype in spark dataframe
df = df.withColumn("date", to_utc_timestamp(date_fn("date"),"UTC"))
```

Is there some way I can add some code that detects non matching formats and then just delets the observation or turns it into null?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) converts a string into a date using a given [format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). If the string does not match the format, the result will be `null`.

There is a small restriction that `to_date` cannot parse the day of the week:

> Symbols of ‘E’, ‘F’, ‘q’ and ‘Q’ can only be used for datetime formatting, e.g. date_format. They are not allowed used for datetime parsing, e.g. to_timestamp.

The easiest way is to remove the first three characters from the date string before using `to_date`:

```python
data = [["Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0000 2021"],
  ["Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0200 2021"],
  ["Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 2021"], 
  ["2021-07-01 15:32:02"], 
  ["this is not a valid time"]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["input"])

df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.substring("input",5,100),
  "MMM dd HH:mm:ss xx yyyy")).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
data = [["Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0000 2021"],...
+------------------------------+----------+
|input                         |date      |
+------------------------------+----------+
|Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0000 2021|2021-07-01|
|Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 +0200 2021|2021-07-01|
|Thu Jul 01 15:32:02 2021      |null      |
|2021-07-01 15:32:02           |null      |
|this is not a valid time      |null      |
+------------------------------+----------+
```